Understanding the Runge-Kutta 2nd order method
The question is in the "coding" context but I'd say it's more math related than python related. I have 2 main questions:

I've always learnt that the Taylor expression is for a function that is $x=x(t)$, it's Taylor expression evaluated at a general $t$ centered at $t_0$:
$$x(t)=x(t_0)+\frac{x'(t_0)}{1!}(t-t_0)+\dots$$
But the one the Runge-Kutta suggests is:
$$x(t+h)=x(t)+h*x'(t)+\dots$$
I don't understand how one is equivalent to the other.
But, I can kind of understand that we can substitute $h=t-t_0$ such that: $$x(t_0+h)=x(t_0)+x'(t_0)h$$ and then you can do $t=t_0$ of some sort to get there? But still I don't know if it's true.
Now the question that actually confuses me the most of the 2. In the  Runge-Kutta (2nd order) suggests that to improve the error, we can do something with the Taylor expansion, that is, evaluating the Taylor expansion at $t+h$ but now with respect to $t+h/2$, how is that possible mathematically? What I mean is, the notes suggests now the following formula:
$$x(t+h)=x(t+h/2)+\frac{1}{2}hx'(t+h/2)+\dots$$
How have we modified the arguments of the right hand side without modifying the argument of the left hand side from the equation I previously said $x(t+h)=x(t)+h*x'(t)$? I can maybe think it's some sort of approximation due to $h$ being so small? But I don't get it still.


I have to confess that I do not remember the details of the Runge-Kutta method, but I do not see the problems in your questions. Namely, let we have the function $x(r)$ with the Taylor expansion $$x(r)=x(r_0)+\frac{x'(r_0)}{1!}(r-r_0)+\dots$$
at $r_0$.
Then it has the following particular cases.

If $r_0=t$, $r=t+h$ then

$$x(t+h)=x(t)+\frac{x'(t)}{1!}h+\dots.$$

If $r_0=t+h/2$, $r=t+h$ then

$$x(t+h)=x(t+h/2)+\frac{x'(t+h/2)}{1!}\cdot\frac h2+\dots.$$

For your first question, you are pretty much there. Essentially, you're doing a Taylor expansion of $x$ around $t$ (so treating $t$ as your $t_0$). Letting $s$ be my "dummy variable'' we could write
$$
x(s) = x(t) + x'(t)(s - t) + \cdots.
$$
We then evaluate this Taylor expansion at $s = t + h$ to get the desired formula.
For the second question, instead perform the Taylor expansion around $t + h/2$. So
$$
x(s) = x(t+h/2) + x'(t+h/2)(s-(t+h/2)) + \cdots.
$$
Then evaluating at $s = t + h$ gives the desired formula.

But on the second question if we evaluate the Taylor expression at $t+h/2$ shouldn't we get: $$x(t+h/2)=x(t)+\frac{x'(t)h)}{2}$$ like you are evaluating it at $s=t+h/2$ but you are not modifying the arguments on the right hand side, aren't we? Like how can we change the arguments on the RHS? Like I'm trying to understand it mathematically strict

In the second question, I'm letting $t_0 = t + h/2$ which is the point we are taking the Taylor expansion "around" (so the expansion approximates the function $x$ near this point). Then I am "evaluating" the approximation at $s = t + h$.
